# How to copy images from gallery to app’s installation directory in React-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-image-picker, rn-fetch-blob

I want to pick an image from gallery and copy that image to the currently running app’s installation directory using react-native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [React Native Image Picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker) to pick an image from Camera Roll or Gallery.

See it's usage code [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker#usage)

To write any file into native file storage, you can use [RNFS](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)

See a basic example [here](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#basic)

Comment: See I want to copy the image as itself without converting it to base64 string. I used react-native-image-picker and from its response I picked the uri and then used rn-fetch-blob as ` RNFetchBlob.fs
          .cp(sourcepath, destinationPath)` . Now I need to check whether the image is copied to destination path as image itself or as uri.